# Use Cache If File Not Changed

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've got a playwright docker image that I am using to test some code. The problem is that our dockerfile contains

```
COPY package.json /app
COPY package-lock.json /app
# patches are used in the `postinstall` script
COPY patches/ /app/patches

# Install the dependencies in Node environment
RUN npm install
RUN npx playwright install
```

However this means that `RUN npm install` runs every single time that package.json updates. This is an issue when changing up scripts that do not touch the package definitions (something we do surprisingly often).

Short of finding a way to separate our scripts from the package.json file is there anything we can do to use the dockerfile's cache if package-lock.json hasn't changed and then copy the package.json file later?

Comment: One approach I've taken is to have a `package.json`, but _not_ use it for dependency download; if `yarn.lock` is what's actually making the decision about what's downloaded, then you can use _that_ as the input to your download process without needing your "real" package.json involved. (Mind, my own workflow involves [`yarn2nix`](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#javascript-yarn2nix))